# Switching to existing chrome browser from desktop application

Tags: karate

I am trying to get control of the existing chrome browser and want to use the same browser for automation, using selenium & Karate.

Here is an actual scenario:

I click a hyperlink from the desktop and it opens in the chrome browser. Now I need to run my automation script in the same browser.

I have the following code, before that, I am starting chrome browser in debugging mode using this link https://harith-sankalpa.medium.com/connect-selenium-driver-to-an-existing-chrome-browser-instance-41435b67affd

```
* def startUrl = "https://google.com"
* def browser = "chrome"
* def type = "chromedriver"
* def executable = "C:/chromedriver/" + type + ".exe"
* def driverConfig = { type: #(type), showDriverLog: true, start:false, executable: # 
(executable), webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: # 
(browser),goog:chromeOptions": { debuggerAddress: 127.0.0.1:9223 }  } } }
* configure driver = driverConfig
Given driver startUrl
* waitFor('input[name=q]')
And input('input[name=q]', 'Youtube')
```

can anyone please confirm how it will be done? I am new to Karate-UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting control of an existing Chrome instance to use Karate UI is only possible if that Chrome instance has been started with [remote-debugging enabled](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

From the command-line, this is typically done by adding this option: `--remote-debugging-port=9222`.

I know a team that uses Karate UI for automating [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/) (Chromium Embedded Framework) used in a desktop application. In this case, the developers of the desktop app made an environment variable drive the [enabling of this debug mode](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?t=15099). For e.g. if the OS env variable `ENABLE_CHROME_DEBUG` had a value equal to `true`, the CEF remote-debugging would be programmatically enabled via the SDK / API.

So you have to figure out some similar approach. If the desktop app is creating a new instance of Chrome, it should be possible to enable the remote debugging also - and you should work with the development team to make this "switchable" for the sake of testability.

Once that is done, Karate has a way to "attach" to an existing Chrome instance via the remote-debug protocol. Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

And note the `attach` config key:

> optional, only for type: 'chrome' and start: false when you want to attach to an existing page in a Chrome DevTools session, uses a "contains" match against the URL

So if you know the URL that has been opened in the browser you want to attach to (even if it is `about:blank`) you can now proceed with testing. You will need only these keys in the `configure driver` data:

- `type: 'chrome'`
- `start: false`
- `attach: 'some/url'` - since this is a "contains" match, the `http` or `https` part can be omitted
- `port: 9222` - change this to use the actual port if different

And `executable` etc. is not needed.

Be aware of a certain quirk when you combine Desktop and Browser testing: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1549#issuecomment-821265333

Comment: Thank you, It worked in debug mode. I had a question when I am running the Web UI script alone it works using a separate feature file but when I run with Robot and web driver in the same feature file then it just attach the existing browser but does not interact with the web elements, am I missing something? Please let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks

Comment: @shashank see the last link in my answer. otherwise I have no idea and you should follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sure, Thank you